# Oracle sample schema for big data

Tags: database, oracle, bigdata, schema

Are there any sample oracle schemas for big data? Specifically searching more than 500K row, multiple column and more than one table.

Comment: you can refer to http://www.tpc.org/   you can download the tool and, obviously, you can generate the data in KB, MB, GB, TB or whatever you want.

Comment: just in case someone comes here looking for 'oracle' and 'big data' - we have a VM for that http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bigdata-appliance/oracle-bigdatalite-2104726.html

Comment: also, the Sales History schema would fit your requirements, 1M rows table, lots of columns, and it's on GitHub https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose I have used TPC benchmarks. You can download a dbgen tool which you can use to generate as much data as you want. You can download it here: http://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/current_specifications.asp